# Content type blocks the formdata key in server end

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

Before upload the file, i have set the content type in header. By adding this header, i am not able to get the formdata in my server side. Before adding the header everything works fine.

```
function uploadFile() {
  var files =  document.getElementById("file1") .files[0] ;
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("MyKey", files);
  ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", "../Save");
  // Before adding below line, working properly//
  ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
  ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

Server side code

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["MyKey"]
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why did you add that header? It is wrong.

Comment: Hi @Musa, Then how to add my custom request header before send the request.

Comment: You can add your custom headers, just don't add `Content-Type`